# Canvas in AsyncTask

Tags: android, canvas, kotlin, android-asynctask, surfaceview

I want to draw many bitmaps on canvas and use this code but it breaks when running. [Cloud_number] is over 50. Here is my code:

class Canvass(context: Context) : View(context) {

```
 override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
      super.onDraw(canvas)        
       cv=canvas
      draw_beautiful_async(canvas)         
       invalidate()

 }
fun draw_beautiful_async(canvas: Canvas) {
    MyDrawingWorkerTask().execute()
}
```

}

```
class MyDrawingWorkerTask() : AsyncTask<Canvas, Void, Void>() {
    
 override fun doInBackground(vararg canvases: Canvas): Void? {
    vt = 0; var x1 = 0f; var y1 = 0f;  var style = 0

    for (i in 1..cloud_number) {
        vt = i * 4 - 3
        style = mt_cloud[vt]
        x1 = mt_cloud[vt + 2].toFloat()
        y1 = mt_cloud[vt + 3].toFloat()            

        cv.drawBitmap(canvas_cloud1, x1, y1, mPaint)

    }
    return null
}
```

}

Comment: maybe when invalidate triggered,your view is just draw ~50 bitMap with this cv.drawBitmap(canvas_cloud1, x1, y1, mPaint).put your onPostExcute to invalidate() the view when it done

Comment: Thank you, but can not put "invalidate()" , android show error.

Comment: use handler to do the invalidate things.not do it inside asynctask

Comment: i am new in kotlin. can you rewrire my code ?

Comment: do you know handle in java,it still work well in kotlin.find out in this [https://medium.com/@ankit.sinhal/handler-in-android-d138c1f4980e]

Comment: I try to put halder in "for (i in 1..cloud_number)" but it still break down.

Comment: do sthing like this. private Handler handler;

    public Async(Handler yourHandler) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
        super.onPostExecute(o);
        Message message = new Message();
        message.what = 12345;
        handler.sendMessage(message);
    }

Comment: Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if(msg.what = 12345)
            invalidate()
        }
    }; and this one inside your view

Comment: android studio can not convert this code to kotlin, i dont how to fix this problem.

Comment: it can.Select Code -> Convert Android to Kotlin on Toolbar.i'm not on my free time so just can draw some draft like that

Comment: Looks like you have to use `SurfaceView` as parent instead of just `View`. Did you try it?

Comment: @shadow: No, i mean i transfer it to kotlin but it still show error in code and i dont know how your code work, it doesnt relate to my canvas.

Comment: @Ircover: can you rewrite my code, i spend over 1 week to just fix this problem.